# Google Analytics is not registering outbound link clicks

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is the Google Analytics code I have in head section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I believe it is NEW Google Universal Analytics code. After adding Analytics code in header, I added links like this.

```
<a href="http://domain.com" rel="external nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://domain.com');return false;ga('send','event','Outgoing Links','http://domain.com','Top content link');">Some text</a>
```

And it's been a month but Google Analytics is not registering outbound link clicks. Do I have to add any additional code somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS **return false;** will go after ga() function call. the code will be:

```
    <a href="http://domain.com" rel="external nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://domain.com');ga('send','event','Outgoing Links','http://domain.com','Top content link'); return false;">Some text</a>
```

Also, use ga like this as you are sending links :

```
    ga('send', 'event', decodeURIComponent('Outgoing Links'), decodeURIComponent('http://domain.com'), decodeURIComponent('Top content link')) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just made the changes and waiting for Google to pick some clicks. BTW why did you suggested to add `decodeURIComponent` in ga function? Any particular reason?

Comment: If you do not do it, you will see % values for special characters. Normally google sends encoded data, so if you decode and send, you will see appropriate data. See my blog on it haidersiddiq.info in javascript section.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Upvote for you. Let Google Analytics register click, then I will report back and accept this answer if everything is OK. :) Thank you for you help.

Comment: @Roberthue Sir, if this helped you, please mark this answer as completed.